# How to display date in lable

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc

```
    using (SqlConnection conn = conMgr.GetDatabaseConnection())
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("getEdit", conn))
        {


            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", id));
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)) 
            { 
                  while (rdr.Read()) 
                     {
                        TextBox1.Text = rdr.GetInt32(rdr.GetOrdinal("id")).ToString(); 
                        TextBox2.Text = rdr.GetString(rdr.GetOrdinal("name"));
                        DropDownList4.SelectedValue = rdr.GetString(rdr.GetOrdinal("country"));
                        string dt = rdr.GetString(rdr.GetOrdinal("dob"));
                        Label14.Text = dt;




                     }  
                rdr.Close();
            }
        }
```

> dob is datetime type. so pleae tell me how can i display it using lable. how do i convert date time object to srting type.

Comment: How about dateValue.ToString("dd MMM yyyy")? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [`GetDateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getdatetime.aspx), then you can use [`ToShortDateString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring.aspx) to get it in the format of dd/mm/yyyy:

```
string dt = rdr.GetDateTime(rdr.GetOrdinal("dob")).ToShortDateString();
Label14.Text = dt;
```